# Uncaught Invariant Violation when filtering list in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I built a list including a search form to filter the list by keyword in React.js with Redux.

This is part of the controller component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    // make a sorted array of the keys in the items object
    var sortedItems = Object.keys(state.items).sort(function(a, b) {
        if(state.items[a].name.toLowerCase() < state.items[b].name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
        if(state.items[a].name.toLowerCase() > state.items[b].name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
        return 0;
    });

    // apply the filter to this array
    sortedItems = filterByKeyword(sortedItems, state.items, state.filter.keyword);

    return {
        items: state.items,
        sortedItems
    }
}
```

This is the filter:

```
export const filterByKeyword = function(sortedItems, items, keyword) {
    keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
    return sortedItems.filter(function(id) {
        return items[id].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) !== -1;
    });
}
```

And this is the list component:

```
const ItemList = ({ items, sortedItems }) => (
    <div>
        {Object.keys(sortedItems).map(function(key) {
            var id = sortedItems[key];

            return (
                <div key={id}>
                    {items[id].name}
                </div>
            );
        }, this)}
    </div>
);
```

Basically this works, but as soon as the keyword is changed, I'm getting an error like this:

``` Uncaught Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.1.0.0.$123): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG-elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``. ```

I also made a version where the filtered items are saved in a second array, while ItemList iterates over all the items and assigns className='hide' to the div if the id is not found in the filtered items array. While this works without errors, it is much too slow.

So, what is the correct React/Redux way to filter a list like this?

Comment: It doesn't seem as if the code presented here is related to the error message. Are you manipulating the DOM in some fashion outside of React? e.g. with jQuery?

Comment: No, it's all React. No jQuery involved.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow ran into the same problem, with a different setup but fundamentally the same thing.

Looks like if you always return a *new* array reference (`sortedItems`) you get a Invariant Violation.

If you instead keep the same reference and remove all items from it then `push` the new ones React knows nothing changed.